# AutoIncrement ID not reseting for rest integration tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, h2

I have a simple rest API using spring boot 2 and Java 11, and I have some integration tests.  Some of the tests insert into the DB and assert that the data is read from the API, and some create objects via the API and assert they can be read back from the DB or the API.

The latter tests, which create objects via the API, seem to not be reseting the auto-increment value in the test h2 database.  The symptom is that the tests pass independently, but not when run as a group - the IDs are the sum of all inserts so far.

I have an @Before method that drops and recreates every table, and an @After method that drops every table, and I've verified that they are running.

There are lots of questions about this but none of the suggested answers make any difference.  I have tried:

- Decorating the test class with @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
- Decorating the test methods with @Transactional
- Running ALTER TABLE person ALTER COLUMN id RESTART WITH 1; repeatedly, including after the table creation and again right before each object creation

My code looks like this:

IntegrationTest.java

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment =  SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public abstract class IntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Before
    public void SetUp() throws SQLException {
        ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(dataSource.getConnection(), new FileSystemResource("src/test/resources/initialization.sql"));
    }

    @After
    public void CleanUp() throws SQLException {
    ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(dataSource.getConnection(), new FileSystemResource("src/test/resources/cleanup.sql"));
    }
}
```

PersonTest.java

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class PersonTest extends IntegrationTest {

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void TestCreatePerson() {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/people";
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setFirstName("Joe");
        p.setLastName("Smith");
        Person r = restTemplate.postForObject(url, p, Person.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, (long) r.getId());
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void TestUpdatePerson() {
        jdbcTemplate.execute("alter table person alter column id restart with 1");
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/people";
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setFirstName("Joe");
        p.setLastName("Smith");
        Person r = restTemplate.postForObject(url, p, Person.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, (long) r.getId()); // FAILS HERE BECAUSE ID == 2
        r.setLastName("Jones");
        restTemplate.put(url, r);
        url = "http://localhost:8080/people/1";
        Person u = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Person.class);
        Assert.assertEquals("Jones", u.getLastName());
    }
```

initialization.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  last_name varchar(128) NOT NULL
);

-- for good measure
ALTER TABLE person ALTER COLUMN id RESTART WITH 1;
```

cleanup.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?